# How can I split an Access report into equal parts?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-access-2007, report

I have an access report based on a query that contains around 160 records. This number varies over time. I would like to be able to split this into 36 equal(ish) parts which will be emailed to various people once a week (each person should receive a unique set of records).

Obviously 160 can't be divided by 36 equally, so for this example some people would receive 4 records and some would receive 5.

I'd like to send the emails using a Macro and the SendObject Action.

Comment: Should this be on Stack Overflow?  (Relates to VBA programming)

Comment: @Breakthrough Quite possibly. I was hoping to avoid programming, but if that's pure wishful thinking then naturally Stack Overflow would be more appropriate.

Comment: Well technically, that's what a macro is (just a VBA function).  If you're comfortable getting your feet wet in VBA, record a macro accomplishing as much as you can for the task (i.e. selecting four records to send to a single person), and then going from there.  If you'd like, you can provide us with some of the code for this and we can go from there... Although that would be a lot more suited to SO.